# How do I substitute a value from axios to input?

Tags: vue.js, axios

This code inserts a value [object Object] in the Name field.
Function `getMarkers()` is work, and function `onMarkerClick()` not work. Tell me how to fix it?

it is possible to take the axios value from the function `getMarkers()` ?
The updated and modified code based on comments now looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <gmap-map
    id="map"
    :center="center"
    :zoom="17"
    @click="addMarker"
  >
    <gmap-info-window
      :options="infoOptions"
      :position="infoWindowPos"
      :opened="infoWinOpen"
      @closeclick="infoWinOpen = false"
    >
      <p>
        Name<input
          id="name"
          v-model="name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
        >
      </p>
    </gmap-info-window>

    <gmap-marker
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :key="index"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="false"
      @click="onMarkerClick"
    />
  </gmap-map>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      center: { lat: 45.029373, lng: 38.972687 },
      type: '',
      address: null,
      name: null,
      markers: [],
      infoContent: '',
      infoWindowPos: null,
      infoWinOpen: false,
      infoOptions: {
        pixelOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: -35
        }
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const vm = this;
    vm.getMarkers();
  },
  methods: {
    getMarkers() {
      const vm = this;
      axios.get('/api/markers')
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.markers = response.data.data.map(m => {
            return {
              name: m.name,
            };
          });
        });
    },

    onMarkerClick(name) {
      this.name = name;
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Remove `{ }` around `name` in `this.name = {name}`, as that is creating an object with a property name whose value is the value of `name` in that context i.e. `{ name: "Example" }`.

Comment: @Marty So the value does not show

Comment: @Marty I updated and modified code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code:

```
onMarkerClick(event, name) { this.name = name; }
```

or to this code:

```
onMarkerClick(event, name) { this.$set(this, "name", name); }
```

Comment: So the Name field is empty

Comment: you are right; name shoud added on template. @click="e => onMarkerClick(e, m.name)"

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the m variable in your v-for into change onMarkerClick. Change your code to this

```
<gmap-marker
      :key="index"
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="false"
      @click="onMarkerClick(m)"
    ></gmap-marker>

  </gmap-map>
```

Now in your clickMarker function should be like this.

```
onMarkerClick(name) {
    this.name = name;
},
```

Comment: then, where 'name' came from ? and where do you trigger onMarkerClick ?

Comment: "Name" not show. And it is possible to take the axios value from the function  getMarkers() ?

Comment: I dont know where your name came from

Comment: from the "markers" table using axios in getMarkers() function